# Error: Could not find or load main class in Jar

Tags: gradle, jar

I build a FatJar with Gradle, but if I execute it i get "Error: Could not find or load main class de.fabipfolix.OlixBotMain"

But it should be there, package and name of the main-class are right.
I renamed (refactored) it once, but even if i changed it back it didn't work.

Gradle:

```
plugins {
id 'java'
}

group 'de.fabipfolix'
version '1.0'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation 'net.dv8tion:JDA:4.1.1_109'
    implementation 'com.jagrosh:jda-utilities:3.0.2'
    implementation group: 'org.xerial', name: 'sqlite-jdbc', version: '3.30.1'
    implementation group: 'com.sedmelluq', name: 'lavaplayer', version: '1.3.34'
}

task createFatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'de.fabipfolix.OlixBotMain'
    }
        from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

Does anyone know what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see examples of how to create "fat" jars in the [Gradle user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:java_packaging). Specifically, you are collecting dependencies from the `compile` configuration, which is deprecated and also unused in your project (you are doing it correctly with the newer `implementation` configuration). But in either case, you should be collecting the runtime dependencies as well as the compiled classes. You also need to depend on the configuration in order to have it resolved.

Here is the way they do it in the user guide:

```
task uberJar(type: Jar) {
    archiveClassifier = 'uber'

    from sourceSets.main.output

    dependsOn configurations.runtimeClasspath
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.findAll { it.name.endsWith('jar') }.collect { zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the [Shadow plugin](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/introduction/) which does all this for you.

Comment: thank you, already tried to replace the compile with implement, but that didn't worked either. Maybe I should get some more informations about gradle.